# Reason for "Cannot resolve dependency to assembly" error

Tags: c#, dll, compiler-errors

When would the following message be shown?

> *Error 1   Unknown build error, 'Cannot resolve dependency to assembly 'Infragistics2.Win.v10.3, Version=10.3.20103.2015, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=7dd5c3163f2cd0cb' because it has not been preloaded. When using the ReflectionOnly APIs, dependent assemblies must be pre-loaded or loaded on demand through the ReflectionOnlyAssemblyResolve event.'*

I have added few DLLs to an existing working project. I know it's difficult to pin point the reason without the details on the code-base, but what I would like to know the general cause for such error messages to appear?

**Note:** *Just created a fresh WPF project and added the bunch of new DLLs. The issue is present there also. Therefore, it's highly likely that the issue is due to organization and content of the DLLs.*

Comment: What does /v:diag show for the assembly resolution step when you build manually?

Comment: Read [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/jmstall/archive/2006/11/22/reflection-type-load-exception.aspx). It might shed some light.

Comment: @Reniuz: I don't actually have a Run Time exception. Simply adding the references and then trying to compile results in the error message.

Comment: This can happen when you have some "designtime" dependencies... for example if you don't install the respective componentes cleanly into GAC

Comment: Try to add System.Drawing to references.

Comment: @Reniuz: I don't think System.Drawing is the issue here.

Comment: I red somewhere that it helped...issue was related with Infragistics and this error.

Comment: @Reniuz: Adding System.Drawing.dll didn't help.

Comment: @Reniuz: Looks like this maybe a problem with the project being WPF. I have created two project, one wpf and one windows Form. I have added the new DLLs to each without referring to them in the code. The Win Form application compiled, but the WPF one failed. Not sure why this is happening, maybe it will be of help in tackling the issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Proper version of Infragistics DLL was missing and adding it resolved the issue.

**Note:** The problem is too localized and hence this solution is useful at local system only.

Comment: I had the same problem with Microsoft.WindowsAzure.ServiceRuntime. Apparently assembly version mismatches can cause this error.

Answer (score 9):

This can happen if your xaml file statically references a view model class and that view model class has a dependency which may not be recognised as missing in the xaml file. You will need to add that dependency to the offending project. Because it is referenced in the xaml file compile time errors aren't clear on the source of the problem.